# QR code scanner with screenshot support on Linux Desktop?

Tags: linux, screenshot, qr-code, arch-linux

#### My demand

I often find myself wanting to get the contents of a QR code on a webpage. The ideal workflow I have in mind is as follows:

1. I hit a hotkey, which triggers this application to launch a screenshot utility
2. I select an area containing the QR code
3. The application shows the QR code's content in a popup/notification

Currently I have to first capture the screenshot and save it, then launch a separate QR scanner utility to scan from file. It's a small annoyance once or twice, but it gets infuriatingly tedious when I have to do it a dozen times daily. So this is a workflow I seek to improve.

#### Personal preferences

I would strongly prefer:

- Works on Xorg
- Free and open source
- Native GUI toolkit (as opposed to things like Electron)

Ideally I would also like (but am willing to forgo):

- Works on Wayland
- QT toolkit (I am using KDE)
- Minimal feature set (do one thing and do it well)
- Existing ArchLinux or AUR package

I do not care about:

- Cross platform (I use Linux exclusively for desktop computing nowadays)
- Doing a little bit of custom setup (e.g. scripts)
- Number of dependencies

Comment: Have you yried bar code reader apps/ programs

Comment: Yes, several. They either provide "scan using camera", "scan using file", or both. But I haven't found one that integrates screenshot capturing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's an app that does it in one go. Screenshots apps on Linux are heavily behind e.g. [ShareX](https://getsharex.com/) in terms of functions and that unfortunately is Windows-only and has that feature.

You can however try to combine few apps:

- some CLI region screenshot grabber like [Flameshot](https://github.com/flameshot-org/flameshot)
- some CLI QR code reader like [zbarimg](https://man.archlinux.org/man/extra/zbar/zbarimg.1.en)
- something to display the result like [notify-send](https://man.archlinux.org/man/notify-send.1.en)
- keyboard shortcut to combine everything and run as a command (should be doable in Arch settings from what I see)

Then you can run something along these lines:

```
flameshot gui --raw | zbarimg --raw - 2>&1 | notify-send -w "QR code output" -
```

- `2>&1` is optional and redirects errors to `stdout` in case you want to know what went wrong, if not, you can use `-q` switch for that command for cleaner output
- `-w` leaves the notification open until manually closed

Comment: I already use flameshot but didn't know it supports piping. That makes it much easier. This will do for now. Thanks.

Comment: Also, I don't think `notify-send` acutally supports stdin input IIRC. I can script my way around it, but just for the sake of accuracy you might wish to edit the answer.

Comment: I'll recheck later, I might have had something else in mind, thanks.